# react-scripts start error code-134, not starting application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, yarnpkg, react-scripts

I'm trying to create a simple electron application for windows with react.js. Everything was fine, suddenly, I'm encountering some error, which doesn't let me run the application :

Error : https://pastebin.com/awMi4UBM (`react-scripts start`)

Error : https://pastebin.com/xeH3A1Dx(`rescripts start`)

My `package.json` partially :

```
   ....
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rescripts start",
    "startb": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rescripts build",
    "test": "rescripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "preelectron-pack": "yarn build",
    "electron-pack": "electron-builder build -mw",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
  },
     ...
```

Pasted here too :

error for `react-scripts start`:

```
yarn run v1.17.3
$ react-scripts start
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from E:\gits\telapoka-dev\telapoka-react\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
Starting the development server...


<--- Last few GCs --->

[2260:0000019DDCF58EB0]   134175 ms: Scavenge 1375.7 (1424.0) -> 1375.4 (1424.5) MB, 11.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.124, current mu = 0.023) allocation failure
[2260:0000019DDCF58EB0]   137527 ms: Mark-sweep 1376.1 (1424.5) -> 1375.8 (1424.5) MB, 3339.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.070, current mu = 0.014) allocation failure scavenge might not su
cceed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0000001B64F5C5C1]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0000001B64F4EC05]
Security context: 0x03045269e6e9 <JSObject>
    2: replace [00000304526905E9](this=0x03b789806cc9 <String[80]: E:\gits\telapoka-dev\telapoka-react\node_modules\react-file-viewer\dist\index.js>,0x014e3ebde1c1 <JSRegExp <String[2]:
 \\>>,0x014cc71b23e1 <String[1]: />)
    3: _append [000001ED43DEE861] [E:\gits\telapoka-dev\telapoka-react\node_modules\@babel\gener...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF761E3C6AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF761E17416 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF761E17D90 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF76213189E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF7621317CF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF762317F94 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF76230EF76 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
 8: 00007FF76230D5CC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
 9: 00007FF762316317 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
10: 00007FF762316396 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
11: 00007FF762440637 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
12: 00007FF7624BD826 v8::internal::operator<<+73494
13: 0000001B64F5C5C1
error Command failed with exit code 134.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Process finished with exit code 134
```

error for `rescripts start`:

```
yarn electron-dev
yarn run v1.17.3
$ concurrently "BROWSER=none yarn start" "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron ."
[0] 'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[0] operable program or batch file.
[0] BROWSER=none yarn start exited with code 1
```

Dependencies :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "copy-clipboard-js": "^1.0.3",
    "dialog": "^0.3.1",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-ace": "^8.0.0",
    "react-awesome-button": "^6.5.1",
    "react-collapsible": "^2.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-file-viewer": "^1.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "react-welcome-page": "^0.2.1",
    "remote": "^0.2.6",
    "wait-on": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

DevDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rescripts/cli": "^0.0.13",
    "@rescripts/rescript-env": "^0.0.11",
    "electron": "^8.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.3.2",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- delete `node_modules`
- clear cache
- delete `temp` folder**s**
- delete `package_lock.json` if exists(should exist if using npm) or `yarn.lock`(if using yarn)
- as we are using react, it is unofficially official that using `npm install` may create some problem, use **`yarn install`**

Everything should work fine.